# I need to make a fill function on Canvas Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, paint

I can't get the x or y of where the user has drawn already.
I'd like to be able to press a <kbd>fill</kbd> button then press in the area, and if a circle has been drawn for example, it would fill with a certain colour.

```
def fill(event):
    global colour
    for x in range(x1,x2):
        x = canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill=colour)
```

Answer (score 0):

To fill an existing element in the canvas there is `.itemconfig`:

```
def fill(canvas, element_id, event):
    canvas.itemconfig(element_id, fill=colour)
```

To bind it to an event there is `.tag_bind`, to which we can pass the unique id of our circle and the above function with the corresponding arguments:

```
canvas.tag_bind(circle, "<Button-1>", lambda e: fill(canvas, circle, e))
```

Where `"<Button-1>"` is the event of a left-click

We can then make it a class to make it cleaner:

```
class FillableOval:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x0, y0, x1, y1, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = self.canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, **kwargs)

        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.id, "<Button-1>", self.fill)

    def fill(self, event):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id, fill=colour)
```

Comment: This is along the right track, would this be appliable to a shape the user has drawn? The shape isnt like a set shape function its just a drawing on Canvas. I understand its an awkward question and Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dylanobrien, if you mean a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill then this won't work; Canvas is not the proper tool for that.

Comment: Yes I meant a flood fill. Ok no problem thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at English.
so
I'll show you a simple example code I made.

```
import tkinter as tk

def draw_start(event):
    line_points.extend((event.x, event.y))
    draw_obj = draw_variety.get()
    if draw_obj == 'circle':
        global obj_id
        obj_id = canvas.create_oval(line_points[0], line_points[1], line_points[0],
                                                 line_points[1], width=1, outline='black')
    if draw_obj == 'fill':
        fill(event)

def state_draw_op(event):
    draw_obj=draw_variety.get()
    if draw_obj == 'circle':
        global obj_id
        canvas.coords(obj_id, line_points[0], line_points[1], event.x, event.y)

def end_draw(event=None):
    draw_obj = draw_variety.get()
    if draw_obj == 'circle':
        global obj_id
        canvas.coords(obj_id, line_points[0], line_points[1], event.x, event.y)
        line_points.clear()

def fill(event):
    color = color_variety.get()
    item = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    canvas.itemconfigure(item, fill=color)

line_points=[]
root=tk.Tk()
canvas=tk.Canvas(root,  relief="solid", bd=2)
canvas.pack()
draw_variety=tk.StringVar()
color_variety=tk.StringVar()
radio_red = tk.Radiobutton(root, value='red', indicatoron=False, relief='flat', bg='red',
                                           height=2, width=5,
                                           overrelief='flat', activebackground='red', highlightcolor='red',
                                           highlightbackground='red', selectcolor='red',
                                           variable=color_variety)
radio_blue = tk.Radiobutton(root, value='blue', indicatoron=False, relief='flat', bg='blue',
                                           height=2, width=5,
                                           overrelief='flat', activebackground='blue', highlightcolor='blue',
                                           highlightbackground='blue', selectcolor='blue',
                                           variable=color_variety)
radio_cir = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='ㅇ', value='circle', indicatoron=False, relief='flat',
                                               font=('Consolas', 20,),
                                               overrelief='flat', command=None,
                                               variable=draw_variety,
                                               selectcolor='red')
radio_fill = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='fill', value='fill', indicatoron=False, relief='flat',
                                               font=('Consolas', 20,),
                                               overrelief='flat', command=None,
                                               variable=draw_variety,
                                               selectcolor='red')

radio_red.pack()
radio_blue.pack()
radio_cir.pack()
radio_fill.pack()
canvas.bind('<Button-1>', draw_start)
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', state_draw_op)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', end_draw)
root.mainloop()
```

In this case, it would be better to use a class, but for the sake of simplicity I used a global variable.

Comment: I'm sorry that the code is messy and I can't explain in detail because I don't speak English. (I rely on Google Translate)